# Python unable to import module despite being installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip

This is yet another issue of a module not being found. I've read countless posts but I've not come across a single one that has helped me fix this issue. The module in question here is "PyOpenSSL" and I'm doing this on a Mac.

Here's the error that I get, running it with Python3:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyopenssl'
```

I've tried installing pyopenssl using pip3 and "python3 -m pip install pyopenssl". Here's the output that I get:

```
pip3 install pyopenssl
Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (19.1.0)
```

Output of:

```
which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
```

```
which -a python
/usr/bin/python
```

My .bash_profile:

```
cat ~/.bash_profile

# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

List of installed modules:

```
pip3 list
Package           Version
----------------- -------
astroid           2.3.3
cffi              1.14.0
click             7.1.1
cryptography      2.8
Flask             1.1.1
isort             4.3.21
itsdangerous      1.1.0
Jinja2            2.11.1
lazy-object-proxy 1.4.3
MarkupSafe        1.1.1
mccabe            0.6.1
pip               20.0.2
pycparser         2.20
pylint            2.4.4
pyOpenSSL         19.1.0
setuptools        41.2.0
six               1.14.0
Werkzeug          1.0.0
wrapt             1.11.2
```

Comment: Can you add more traceback apart from `Module not found error`? Are you running it in a virtualenv?

Comment: Is `pyopenssl` listed when you run `python3 -c 'help("modules")'` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito - It isn't...

Answer (score 1):

In `PyOpenSSL` the module to import is named **OpenSSL**:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL  # for example
```

See the [docs](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/ssl.html) and the [code](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/tree/master/src/OpenSSL).